# ArcGIS Jupyter Notebooks - calling the attribute Id

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, arcgis-notebook, hosted-feature-layer

I am looking to list field properties and I can't seem to find the parameter that will call the attribute id for the layer. What properties can you call?

Examples:

```
['name']
['alias']
```

What I am looking for is the attribute id : 0, 1, 2,......

```
for f in featureLayer.properties.fields:
     print (f['name'],['alias'])
```

returns a list with the field name and the alias like:

```
Street_Name Street Name
Insp_Date Inspection Date
```

Can you provide me the answer or direct me to the proper documentation?

Answer (score 1):

This code goes over the entire database and looks for just FeatureClasses and Tables.  Maybe try this:

```py
import arcpy, os

psg = "<your_db>"
datatype = ["FeatureClass", "Table"]
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(psg, datatype=datatype)
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:       
    for file in filenames:
        print(f"---->  {file}  <----")
        fpath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
        fields = arcpy.ListFields(fpath)
        for field in fields:
            print(field.name, field.aliasName)
```

If you are looking for docs, try:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/describe.htm

More specific:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/field.htm

Additionally, to get properties for objects like these you can do a

print(dir(field))

an example of using print(dir(field)) is used in next snippet.

Alternatively, if you are wanting to see the properties of layers in a ArcGIS Pro project map, you can try:

```py
import arcpy
from pprint import pprint

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps("my_map")[0]

# all layers in map
for lyr in m.listLayers():
    if lyr.isFeatureLayer:
        print(f"--->  {lyr.name}  <---")
        desc = arcpy.da.Describe(lyr)
        for field in desc["fields"]:
            print(f"{field.name} == {field.aliasName}")

# just one layer
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps("my_map")[0]
lyr = m.listLayers("*my_lyr")[0]
# lyr = m.listLayers("*map_unit_polys")[0]
desc = arcpy.da.Describe(lyr)
pprint(desc)
for field in desc["fields"]:
    print(dir(field))
```

Comment: This may work for a feature class is a database but, I am looking at a hosted feature class in AGOL and calling the functions from the RestAPI.  As a work around i have been copying and pasting the list into excel to get the order and therefore count but, i didn't know if there was a better way.  Thank you for the reply and i will test that in my next database task.

Answer (score 0):

Using arcgis API, got it:

```py
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer

gis = GIS() # may need credentials
lyr_url = "the_url"
layer = FeatureLayer(lyr_url)
for f in layer.properties.fields:
    print(dir(f))
    print(f"{f.name} | {f.alias}")
```